# Tag auto-completion shows tags I'm not allowed to use

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, tag-autocomplete

When using tag auto-completion on MetaSO, it includes moderator-only tags (like status-completed). Not only that, it lets me click on them. Shouldn't they be filtered out for mere mortals? (Or at least not selectable?)

Related: When editing a post there shouldn't be a remove-tag button for moderator-only tags.

Comment: This is consistent with many other things, for example you can click upvote or downvote on deleted posts, just to see a red alert showing up. :)

Answer (score 3):

This really isn't a problem since when you click "Save Edit" or "Post a Question" it:

- Doesn't allow you to make those changes
- Gives you a clear error message describing which tag is moderator only
- Saves all the form fields so you don't lose any editing you were doing when it reloads

You might call this a small user interface issue, but I wouldn't even call it that since the three of the above solve the problem with little to no inconvenience for the user. Not to mention moderator only tags are only on Meta (like you said), so if it is an inconvenience, it still doesn't affect most SE users.